# How to bring an application to the front, no bouncing dock icons

Tags: applescript

In my AppleScript, I use `activate` to bring an application to the front. However, on machines of some colleagues, it doesn't do that. The app-icon in the dock will bounce, but it doesn't get put into the front. This is very annoying, because the user has to go to the app manually every time.

I suspect this is due to some setting or something. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

did you check if "visible" is true or false in your applescript Code?

Looks like the app is running in the background.

Try to set the app to the frontmost window.

If you want to delete the bouncing, it's in the Systeme Preferences, Dock, untick animated apps when open.

Hope that will help you.